# Ideas to highlight various areas of a Single Page Web Application

Tags: website-design, page-layout, highlights

I have created the following page.

[image]

I have created a textured background, borders for two sections in the page.

1. Search Results
2. Selected Images

What I want is an effective way of highlighting the titles "Search Results", "70 Results Loaded" & "2 - Images Selected"

I have tried using different backgrounds, but it just looks ugly. Borders look out of place.

I am open to suggestions and ideas, even if it involves a redesign. The basic operation of the app is

1. Searching for a topic.
2. Displaying the results in one section.
3. User clicking images, thereby transferring them to the selected images section.
4. Some operations on the selected images.

I have limited design knowledge, so I have made a preliminary, fully functional version. Just looking to improve the design further.

Comment: I, personally, find the typeface choice pretty bad and the largest issue with clarity and readability.

Answer (score 1):

To Highlight the titles, or make them more noticeable and easily read you can use some typography tricks:

Make them bigger, make them bolder, in a clearer font (a script font does not catch the eye, it is not immediately and subconsciously read as a word).

I would Left justify them with the section they are titling, Not centered.

Because your background is light you should contrast with dark text.

"70 Results found" should come immediately after "Search Results".

This was not asked for but I think the wording would be clearer and less redundant if it said : "Search Results: 70 Items" and "Images Selected: 2"

Comment: Thank you. Points noted on darker text, placements of results count text and left justification. Is the overall layout OK?